# Is there a way to specify a BASE_DIR setting in python available to all scripts in a package?

Tags: python

I have a script that is writing output to files.

The problem is that it will write the file in different locations depending on where it is called from.

Is there a way to set a `BASE_DIR` setting so that all scripts in this package will write files to a single location?

I've attempted to intialise this to the root of the project in the root's `__init__.py`:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

In my tests, that code is not run as:

```
*** NameError: name 'BASE_DIR' is not defined
```

Comment: Why you provide `os.path.dirname` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need to import the `BASE_DIR` variable in every module you're using it.

If '**my_pkg**' is the root directory of your package, then you should do something like that:

**my_pkg/__init__.py:**

```
BASE_DIR = ... # as you have
```

**my_pkg/some_module.py:**

```
from my_pkg import BASE_DIR
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your package name is mypackage. After you add `BASE_DIR` into `mypackage/__init__.py`, you still need add this line on top of each script in mypackage:

```
from mypackage import BASE_DIR
```

This way, you can access `BASE_DIR` from every script in the package.